# Retrieving the 'help' docstrings on an object in python

Tags: python, documentation

I'm trying to use `pydoc.render_doc(object)` to get the help documentation on an object as a string. However for some reason, doing so makes all the method names of the given object show up very strange; every other character is '\x08' and letters are grouped by two. For example, `__new__` `____nneeww____` ('\x08' doesn't render here for some reason). Any ideas on what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pydoc` has to be pretty ancient module.

## `pydoc` makes noise of mechanical printer

The `\x08` character is backspace and what I saw made me smile for a moment:

```
>>> pydoc.render_doc(object)
'Python Library Documentation: class object in module __builtin__\n\nclass o\x08ob\x08bj\x08je\x08ec\x08ct\x08t\n |  The most base type\n'
```

It seems, like the default expectation of this module is to print the output to real mechanical printer.

There the backspace causes the carriage to move one character back, and the repeated characters are there to print it once more over backspaced position.

This could result in having it printed bold on mechanical printer.

If you want to get rid of this special decorations, use `pydoc.plain`:

```
>>> pydoc.plain(pydoc.render_doc(object))
'Python Library Documentation: class object in module __builtin__\n\nclass object\n |  The most base type\n'
```

## A bit of history (2001)

Python stdlib doc claims, `pydoc` is `New in version 2.1.`

Wikipedia claims, the [Python 2.1 was released April 17, 2001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_release_dates)